# jQuery Plugin Error with .wrap() and .wrapAll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

> **Note:** I've solved major issues with this question however I still do not have working code, since what I am doing now is a completely different issue I will open a new question solve it there and then post the answer to this question. I'll also add the link to the question. You can see my current progress here: http://jsbin.com/upatus/2/edit

I'm writing two basic jQuery plugins, `$.fn.query` and `$.fn.build`, that sort an array, and create html code to insert into a document, respectively. I'm currently testing it with Vimeo video ID's that I will display videos with.

The `$.fn.query` is working fine, and I'm getting an error with the following code

```
$.fn.build = function(params) {

    // Parameters //
    var options = $.extend( {
            'wrapAll'  : undefined,
            'splitBy'  : undefined,
            'wrapRow'  : undefined,
            'wrapEach' : '<div>'
        }, params),
        build;

    // Wrap Each //
    if (options.wrapEach !== undefined) {
        build = this.wrap(options.wrapEach);
    }

    // Split into Rows //
    if (options.splitBy !== undefined && options.wrapRow !== undefined) {
        var tmp;
        for (var i = build.length; i > 0; i -= 3) {
            tmp = build.splice(i, i + 3).wrapAll(options.wrapRow);
        }
        build = tmp;
    }

    // Wrap All //
    if (options.wrapAll !== undefined) {
        build = build.wrapAll(options.wrapAll);
    }

    // Return Build //
    return build;
};
```

Then calling (both) functions:

```
var query = $(example).query({
     shuffle: true,
       limit: 6
}).build({
     wrapAll: '<div class="container" />',
     splitBy: 3,
     wrapRow: '<div class="row" />',
    wrapEach: '<div class="span4" />'
});
```

Resulting the following error

> Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

Which isn't entirely helpful because it's showing a jQuery error, which seems to exist in a [million different places](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Uncaught%20Error:%20NOT_FOUND_ERR:%20DOM%20Exception%208).

You can see my javascript code on jsFiddle here

> http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/PK2tF/

---

> **PS:** I am trying to follow best practices at all times so if you notice anything even slightly off please let me know and I'll fix the code.

Comment: Use complete html elements. `<div />` otherwise you may run into cross-browser issues. This isn't what is causing the errors, but will cause problems down the road.

Comment: `$.fn.query` is returning an array that doesn't contain dom nodes, then you are acting on it as if it is an array of dom nodes. That definitely won't work.

Comment: @KevinB Is there an easy fix to this, or do I have to create elements (Dom nodes) for each item?

Comment: I would suggest not using the `$.fn` object for this particular plugin.

Comment: @KevinB could you show me what you mean?

Comment: This for example would be `$.query`: http://jsfiddle.net/qcRQH/ `$.build` would need to be done similarly(will take a little longer).

Comment: @KevinB that breaks everything. http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/PK2tF/11/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16115/discussion-between-james-kyle-and-kevin-b)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing jQuery DOM functions with Array manipulations. There is little reason to chain both in a jQuery prototype since the operations a very separate.

Also, the `$.fn.build` does not build upon an element created before the prototype is called, instead you are doing some `wrapAll` methods inside it. Why not bring an outside container instead and build the DOM structure inside it based on the data?

Try something like:

```
$.query = function(data, options) {
    // do the array thingie with data
    return data;
};

$.fn.build = function(data, options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        // do the DOM thingies based on data and the context element.
        // don’t use wrapAll, bring an outside element instead
    });
}
```

And then

```
$('<div>').addClass('container').build( $.query(example), {
    splitBy: 3,
    wrapRow: '<div class="row" />',
    wrapEach: '<div class="span4" />' 
}).appendTo('body');
```

You can also disguise the `$.query` call inside the plugin:

```
$.fn.build = function(options) {
    options.data = $.query( options.data );
    // etc

$('<div>').addClass('container').build({
    data: example,
    splitBy: 3,
    wrapRow: '<div class="row" />',
    wrapEach: '<div class="span4" />' 
}).appendTo('body');
```