# creating DOM nodes from arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, dom-node

> **Note:** This is a continuation of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222477/jquery-plugin-error-with-wrap-and-wrapall) that I decided were two separate issues that need to be solved.  I'm also currently not sure of how exactly to phrase this question, so I will try my best and when I get more clarity I will rephrase my question for future reference.

I'm writing two basic jQuery plugins, `$.fn.query` and `$.fn.build`, that sort an array, and create html code to insert into a document, respectively. I'm currently testing it with Vimeo video ID's that I will display videos with.

`$.fn.build` has three parts. First it wraps every array item with individual containers, the builds them into rows (*problem area*), then lastly it wraps everything in a container. (every part of this is optional).

Specifically the problem comes from this line: `$(tmp).add(newRow);` although it is valid javascript.

```
if ( options.splitBy !== undefined && options.wrapRow !== undefined ) {
    var tmp = $([]),
        newRow = function(i) {
            $(build.splice( i, i + options.splitBy )).wrapAll( options.wrapRow ).parent();
        };

    for (var i = 0, l = build.length, a = options.splitBy; i < l; i += a) {
        $(tmp).add(newRow);
    }

    build = tmp;
    console.log(build);
}
```

> See: http://jsbin.com/upatus/2/edit

Comment: a little side note: when using [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) you'll need to use the return value.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure that you want to use the function, instead of adding the function itself. Also, you will want to use the same `tmp` object all over the time, instead of wrapping it into a new jQuery instance and not adding to the original one. Try

```
tmp.add(newRow(i));
```

BTW: If you want to build an array, you should use

```
var tmp = [];
```

and

```
tmp.push(…);
```

---

Now I've looked at the code from the other question. Both answers are correct, and contain some valid points:

- `splice` is an Array function on jQuery's prototype, and returns an array. (You have fiexd this now)
- Your `query` method returns an array, but should return a jQuery instance for chaining
- Your `build` variable was not initialized, but used

You should really choose whether you want to use arrays or jQuery objects internally in your function, and not mix them.

BTW, you should rename your functions to more descriptive names. "build" and "query" are very vague and may collide with other plugins.

Comment: That helps but there it's still not working: http://jsbin.com/upatus/4/edit

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger. Alternatively, jsbin has a console and some automatic warnings.